# cuda Texture declaration compile-time error

Tags: cuda, textures

I'm trying to compile the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

texture<float, 2, cudaReadModeElementType> tex;

int main () { ... }
```

yet, nvcc gives me the following error:

```
main.c:6:8: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘<’ token
```

I'm pretty new to CUDA, so I suppose I'm missing something here.

Comment: You can only use CUDA syntax in `.cu` files.

Comment: Yup, I switched from `main.c` to `main.cu` and now it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use CUDA syntax in .cu files.

Comment: Actually that texture declaration is only a C++ template instantiation, not anything CUDA specific. The code would compile if a C++ rather than C compiler were used, nvcc or a .cu extension isn't required in this particular case.